# maven project convert to Eclipse classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to convert maven project to Eclipse project, I have run this command, mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse , it did generate .project and .classpath file, .project looks like correct, but .classpath file is wrong, it didn't add source folder and third-party library.

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: What Eclipse version?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your use case? Are you just looking to import a maven project into eclipse? Or are you required to generate all the files independently of Eclipse?  If the former, you should use m2e (see answer from @MariuszS below.  If the latter, `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is better.

Comment: my IDE version is RSA 6.0

Comment: Wow. That is old.  What version of Eclipse is it based on? I think it is less than 3.4.  If so, then you will not be able to install m2e into your RSA.  Do you really need to use such and old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about [Eclipse Integration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration) project?

### [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)

> Maven Integration for Eclipse provides tight integration for Maven into the IDE with the following features:
>
> - Launching Maven builds from within Eclipse
> - Dependency management for Eclipse build path based on Maven's pom.xml
> - Resolving Maven dependencies from the Eclipse workspace without installing to local Maven repository
> - Automatic downloading of the required dependencies from the remote Maven repositories
> - Wizards for creating new Maven projects, pom.xml and to enable Maven support on plain Java project
> - Quick search for dependencies in Maven remote repositories
> - Quick fixes in the Java editor for looking up required dependencies/jars by the class or package name

Comment: The more common name for this project is m2e.